# Recurly.js and Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, recurly

I'm using an angular reactive form and trying to get a token from Recurly.js.

I've used the recurly suggested name for the input and added the `data-recurly="number"` for the cc number and so on.

On submit first I call `recurly.configure()` and then I take the value from the reactive form and pass it to `recurly.token()` in this way:

```
recurly.token(this.form.value, function (err, token) {
    if (err) {
      // handle error using err.code and err.fields
      console.log("Recurly token error: " + err);
    } else {
      // handle success using token.id
      console.log("Recurly token success: " + token.id);
    }
  });
```

`this.form.value` contains the correct field names and values but I always get the following validation error:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Dem

Comment: You should call `recurly.configure()` before you submit.

Answer (score 3):

### Quick Update

Since the release of [Elements](https://developers.recurly.com/reference/recurly-js/index.html#elements), [Recurly.js](https://developers.recurly.com/reference/recurly-js/index.html) should be compatible with any modern framework, including [Vue](https://github.com/dbrudner/rjs-vue-demo), [Angular](https://github.com/dbrudner/recurly-angular-example), and [Electron](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-js-examples/tree/main/electron). A [React](https://github.com/recurly/react-recurly) library is also available.

If anyone comes across this message and is experiencing an issue using Recurly.js with any modern front-end framework, please consider [opening an issue with the library](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-js/issues/new).

Answer (score 1):

So basically we cannot use reactive forms and recurly support told me they don't support Angular or React (guys, it's 2017!) so we are stuck using their form system that is quite bad if you tell me.

However, in case somebody else needs it, I've created a demo project with a recurly form component that can be easily customised and integrated:

https://github.com/demetrio812/angular-recurly-test

One thing to notice is that multiple forms in the same page aren't supported by Recurly.js library.

Cheers,

Dem